# 2 times the data results from the operater "Process documents from data" in Rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

I'm new with rapidminer and tried to read rss feeds and put it in some files like this tutorial on vimeo (https://vimeo.com/62963128). Almost everything works, but I have one problem. The process generates every file twice. File 1 and 21 are the same file, file 2 and 22 are the same file, and so on. Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

This is the code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="6.5.002">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.5.002" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <parameter key="logverbosity" value="init"/>
    <parameter key="random_seed" value="2001"/>
    <parameter key="send_mail" value="never"/>
    <parameter key="notification_email" value=""/>
    <parameter key="process_duration_for_mail" value="30"/>
    <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="web:read_rss" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read RSS Feed" width="90" x="112" y="255">
        <parameter key="url" value="http://www.autoblog.com/category/recap/rss.xml"/>
        <parameter key="random_user_agent" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="connection_timeout" value="10000"/>
        <parameter key="read_timeout" value="10000"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="web:retrieve_webpages" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Get Pages" width="90" x="514" y="435">
        <parameter key="link_attribute" value="Link"/>
        <parameter key="page_attribute" value="myhtml"/>
        <parameter key="random_user_agent" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="connection_timeout" value="10000"/>
        <parameter key="read_timeout" value="10000"/>
        <parameter key="follow_redirects" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="accept_cookies" value="none"/>
        <parameter key="cookie_scope" value="global"/>
        <parameter key="request_method" value="GET"/>
        <parameter key="delay" value="none"/>
        <parameter key="delay_amount" value="1000"/>
        <parameter key="min_delay_amount" value="0"/>
        <parameter key="max_delay_amount" value="1000"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text:process_document_from_data" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Process Documents from Data" width="90" x="715" y="345">
        <parameter key="create_word_vector" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="vector_creation" value="TF-IDF"/>
        <parameter key="add_meta_information" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="keep_text" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="prune_method" value="none"/>
        <parameter key="prune_below_percent" value="3.0"/>
        <parameter key="prune_above_percent" value="30.0"/>
        <parameter key="prune_below_rank" value="0.05"/>
        <parameter key="prune_above_rank" value="0.95"/>
        <parameter key="datamanagement" value="double_sparse_array"/>
        <parameter key="select_attributes_and_weights" value="false"/>
        <list key="specify_weights"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="web:extract_html_text_content" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Extract Content" width="90" x="112" y="30">
            <parameter key="extract_content" value="true"/>
            <parameter key="minimum_text_block_length" value="5"/>
            <parameter key="override_content_type_information" value="true"/>
            <parameter key="neglegt_span_tags" value="true"/>
            <parameter key="neglect_p_tags" value="true"/>
            <parameter key="neglect_b_tags" value="true"/>
            <parameter key="neglect_i_tags" value="true"/>
            <parameter key="neglect_br_tags" value="true"/>
            <parameter key="ignore_non_html_tags" value="true"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="web:unescape_html" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Unescape HTML Document" width="90" x="313" y="30"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:write_document" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Write Document" width="90" x="514" y="30">
            <parameter key="overwrite" value="true"/>
            <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="write_file" compatibility="6.5.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Write File" width="90" x="715" y="165">
            <parameter key="resource_type" value="file"/>
            <parameter key="filename" value="d:\test\%{t}-%{a}.txt"/>
            <parameter key="mime_type" value="application/octet-stream"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="document" to_op="Extract Content" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Extract Content" from_port="document" to_op="Unescape HTML Document" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Unescape HTML Document" from_port="document" to_op="Write Document" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Write Document" from_port="document" to_port="document 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Write Document" from_port="file" to_op="Write File" to_port="file"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_document" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Read RSS Feed" from_port="output" to_op="Get Pages" to_port="Example Set"/>
      <connect from_op="Get Pages" from_port="Example Set" to_op="Process Documents from Data" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Process Documents from Data" from_port="example set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you turn off `create word vector` for the `Process Documents` operator, you should find that you get 20 files. I can't explain it.